# Querying for greatest value of Range key on AWS DynamoDb

Tags: boto, amazon-dynamodb

What is the DynamoDB equivalent of

```
SELECT MAX(RANGE_KEY) FROM MYTABLE WHERE PRIMARYKEY = "value"
```

The best I can come up with is

```
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table as awsTable

tb = awsTable("MYTABLE")
rs = list(tb.query_2(PRIMARYKEY__eq="value", reverse=True, limit=1))
MAXVALUE = rs[0][RANGE_KEY]
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: this is the way to go.

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's the correct way.

Because the records matched by the Hash Key are sorted by the Range Key, getting the first one by the descendant order will give you the record with the maximum range key.

> Query results are always sorted by the range key. If the data type of
>   the range key is Number, the results are returned in numeric order;
>   otherwise, the results are returned in order of ASCII character code
>   values. By default, the sort order is ascending. To reverse the order
>   use the ScanIndexForward parameter set to false.

Query and Scan Operations - Amazon DynamoDB : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html

NOTE: Setting the `reverse` parameter to true via boto API is equivalent to setting `ScanIndexForward` to false via the native AWS API.

Comment: When I query it is returning, all the records with the specified hash key, reverse sorted by range key. Is it possible to get **that only record** with the greatest range key?

Comment: Yes , set the "limit" parameter to 1: "The DynamoDB Query and Scan APIs allow a Limit value to restrict the size of the results."

Comment: I posted a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983291/dynamodb-querying-for-the-greatest-value-of-a-range-key/35984890#35984890). In fact, that did not work. I had to use queryPage of DynamoDBMapper

Comment: What would be the equivalent syntax in boto3? If all my hashkeys are the same the query returns the entire table, but sorted. Does not seem to be efficient. Is this still the way to do it it boto3?

Answer (score 13):

If someone looking how to do it with Java:

```
QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec();
        querySpec.withKeyConditionExpression("PRIMARYKEY = :key")
                .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                        .withString(":key", primaryKeyValue));
        querySpec.withScanIndexForward(true); 
        querySpec.withMaxResultSize(1);
```

Comment: Note that to get the greatest range key you need to pass false to withScanIndexForward. But overall your code fragment works, thanks.

Comment: Hi I have a similar use case, I have 1 doubt, if you are querying by primary key, other filters aren't useful then?

Comment: I guess primary key is a bit confusing, it is a hash key, which is not unique. The primary key is made of hash and rangekey combination

Answer (score 7):

In boto3 you can do it this way:

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

kce = Key('table_id').eq(tableId) & Key('range').between(start, end)
output = table.query(KeyConditionExpression = kce, ScanIndexForward = False, Limit = 1)
```

output contains the row associated with the Max value for the range between start and end. For the Min value change the `ScanIndexForward` to `True`