# DynamoDB - Querying for the greatest value of a range key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, secondary-indexes

I have a DynamoDB table which has the following structure

```
    HK      |    RK      |   A1   |   A2  |   A3
(Hash Key)  | (Range Key)
```

I have a local secondary index whose **range key** is **A3**.

I want to find out for a specific **Hash key HK**, what is the greatest value of the attribute **A3**. So I query the secondary index like this:

```
Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<>();
eav.put(":v1", new AttributeValue().withS("hash value"));
queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Table>()
        .withIndexName("index-name")
        .withKeyConditionExpression("HK = :v1")
        .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav)
        .withScanIndexForward(false);  //This will sort the result in descending order (w.r to range key)

queryExpression.setLimit(1);
myCollection = dynamoDBMapper.query(Table.class, queryExpression);
```

The problem is that it returns **all the records** with the specified hash key, reverse sorted by range key(A3). I want to get the first record alone. (The record with the largest value for A3 for a given HK).

I tried with *setLimit*, but it is not working.

How can I achieve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using `queryPage` rather than `query`

```
QueryResultPage<Lookup> res = dynamoDBMapper.queryPage(Table.class, queryExpression);
```

More info [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=204649&tstart=0)