# How to query the greates value (sortkey/range) dynamodb?

Tags: node.js, database, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Maybe this is a very simple question but I didn't find a suitable solution for this. I have a secondary key /range key /sort key, what ever and its value
is a number. So in the Table a several items with this key and I want to get the Item with 
the greatest number/value. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457799/querying-for-greatest-value-of-range-key-on-aws-dynamodb) at stack overflow but this does not look like something
from the aws [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#query-property). In this documentation you can find gt or ge but I don't want to compare
the value with a number, I want the greatest ... Maybe you can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the property you want to query is your sort/range key, you only need to set `ScanIndexForward=false` (order descending) and set the `Limit` to 1

Comment: Yeah I thought about limit too but I am fighting with the order stuff :P I'll let you know if I get this done

Comment: Thank you , I found this too but i get several errors for my query. I need to fix my syntax first

Comment: Thank you! For reference, from the cli the options are called --no-scan-index-forward (with a no-, instead of specifying that it is false) and --limit (currently not documented in the CLI reference)